# How can I load a specific url page using Firebase Hosting for Flutter Web

Tags: flutter-web, firebase-hosting, flutter-getx

I'm using Getx for navigation which internally uses Navigator 2.0. I'm unable to load a specific URL when I Host in Firebase Hosting.

It seems to be working fine locally.

I'm using Url Path Strategy to remove the #

Comment: In the file `web/index.html`: Is the base that set to `<base href="/">`?

Comment: so what happens when you try to load specific url?

Comment: @Bharath Firebase Hosting will attempt to serve a page for that URL, which doesn't exist, and thus result in a 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you correctly rewrite all requests to /index.html

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "www",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
    ...
```

Deploy again afterwards.